# Using Bootstrap modal instead of Colorbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, colorbox

I have the following javascript which triggers colorbox to open specific PHP pages with parameters on the server:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'input', function () { 
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();

        $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"700px", height:"80%", href:"session_edit.php?ID="+data[0]});
        $(".iframe2").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"700px", height:"80%", href:"index_b.html?ID="+data[0]});
        $(".iframe3").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"300px", height:"20%", href:"delete.php?ID="+data[0], onLoad: function() {
            $('#cboxClose').remove()        
        }});

    });
});
```

No I would like to make use of Bootstrap modal instead of colorbox. I have tried:

```
$("#iframe").modal('show');
```

But it does not work and do not also know how to specify the PHP file with ?ID=

Any idea how I can solve this please?

thanks

Comment: did you include bootstrap.js?

Comment: yes i included `<script
 src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Look at this fiddle to see how to use bootstrap modal: http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/974/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is bit unclear what is not working but i think you are trying to load a remote php file into bootstrap modal which is not showing just like in color-box and want to replace color-box with bootstrap modal

you can add remote file like this inside bootstrap modal call button `href="session_edit.php?ID=<?php echo $id;?>">` and specify the PHP file with ?ID=

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#iframe" href="session_edit.php?ID=<?php echo $id;?>">Open Modal</button>
```

You don't need jQuery to call modal, let bootstrap default modal functionality do it's job

To trigger the modal window, you need to include the two data-* attributes:

```
data-toggle="modal" //opens the modal window
data-target="#iframe" //points to the id of the modal
```

So you don't need this jQuery code to show the bootstrap modal

```
$("#iframe").modal('show');
```

and Modal HTML will be

```
<div class="modal fade" id="iframe" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
         //Content loads here
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

also in remote php file you can add `moda-header`, `modal-body` and `modal-footer`

remote php `session_edit.php`

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Heading</center></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    //Show what ever content here you like it will load into the modal
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

in last, you may need to refresh the modal content if you are dealing with multiple modals on same page without page refresh

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#iframe').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this help.